# Of all methods of FTL travel (or as close as one can get to it), what would be the most feasible to have been invented in the next 100 years?

Tags: science-based, technology, space-travel, spaceships

It's the late 2020's, and humanity has expressed an unprecedented and powerful renewal in the interest of space exploration. Sometime between then and the turn of the next century, a practical form of space travel was invented, allowing the distance between worlds to be traveled in a reasonable time. Bygone are the clunky early ships relying on [pulsed nuclear detonations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_pulse_propulsion) and [lasers beamed up from the ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_propulsion), all replaced by... **what, exactly?**

I'd prefer at least semi-hard answers (anything that has a base in real or proposed theories) as a baseline, but in reality I'm trying to find a solution/method that strikes the best balance between hardness/feasibility of science and practicality of usage in a narrative, so it's just whatever works in the end.

As for what defines "practicality of usage in a narrative"... Well, it'd be really nice for manned missions to nearby solar systems and back to not be a commitment of a large chunk of one's mortal lifespan and time back on Earth. I think 5 years to Alpha Centauri (4.37 ly away) would be the upper cusp of what is considered acceptable in this instance.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit.** If it helps, assume feasible nuclear fusion power was invented early on in the period of time specified by the question.

Comment: In my opinion, even with the current technology development curve, I still struggle to see any FTL travel possible within the next 100 years. Especially since we're not even close to close-to-light travel. Having said that, I really hope I am wrong.

Comment: why do you consider Laser propulsion clunky? it can theoretically take you to a high fraction of the speed of light and allows the ship to not be weighed down by a large mass of fuel.

Comment: @RandySavage
Laser propulsion really isn't clunky at all by our standards today. Neither is pulsed nuclear propulsion. I just used that term to emphasize how this hypothetical new method of space travel is so revolutionary it makes those seem "clunky" by comparison.

Comment: @ZarHakkar I see what you mean, all faster options seem too advanced for the limited time of 100 years, I could see laser highways between star systems as an efficient method of travel for many more centuries to come.

Comment: Seriously speaking, I doubt the humanity could reach even small-percentage of c in manned flights.

We're searching for superconductors for quite a while and the best we could find breaks down (as superconductor) at 32 Tesla.

We hardly can move 100 tones on LEO, a good percentage less inside the solar system.

Bending space-time? With what?

Comment: As an aside, nuclear fusion is really more of an engineering challenge at this point instead of a basic science challenge. Properly funded we would see commercial nuclear fusion in as little as 20-30 years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Alcubierre Drive**

Though still highly theoretical, the [Alcubierre Drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) (the brainchild of Mexican physicist Miguel Alcubierre, is generally thought [the most likely candidate for actual FTL](https://www.sciencealert.com/how-feasible-is-a-warp-drive-here-s-the-science).

Basically, the Alcubierre Drive achieves FTL travel by stretching the fabric of space-time in a wave, causing the space ahead of it to contract while the space behind it expands. Rather than moving FTL as such, it is moving spacetime itself, and hence will not be subject to relativistic effects like space and time dilation.

We still have quite a ways to go before realizing an Alcubierre Drive (if it is even possible), but don't forget that it only took 65 years to go from the first powered aircraft to have people landing on the Moon and coming back. We have more time than that before the end of the century.

[image]

Comment: If I recall correctly, an efficient Alcubierre drive requires a track of exotic matter to be laid to the destination.

Comment: @BMF For Monica It's not about efficiency, it's about how a drive requires the space ahead of you to curve faster than c, which would be FTL information transmission. A tunnel does not require information to travel faster than light and is thus less problematic relativity wise.

Comment: @Muuski Right. Dumping all that money and energy into an AWD that goes *nowhere* because there exists no tunnel is still inefficient lol

Answer (score 2):

Out of all variations of FTL travel, the only one that seems remotely feasible is by space-time-distorion (e.g. the Warp drive). But that would require humanity to develop a technology that allows for the generation of artifical gravity wells in front of their ships.

I would give it a minimal chance that humanity dicoveres some intricate knowledge about gravity altering quantum particles in the next 100 years. But the same has been said about discovering particles smaller than an atom and than smaller then an electron, so it could be entirely possible in the scope of your story.

Comment: Why would you give it a minimal chance when there are currently experiments that are very well funded looking into exactly this sort of thing? Particle physics has a lot of momentum right now and produces exciting discoveries all the time. I would say the chances of discovery is 100% multiplied by the existence of such particles.

Comment: @Muuski because there is a massive difference between knowing 'yes there should be something that does this' and 'we found the particle resposible for this phenomenon and know how to utilize it. Take the Higgs-Boson for an example, the idea existed since the 1960s, the first proof was made 2012 and the data is still not fully analyzed.